# Unable to insert multiple (100+) rows into my table in PHP MyAdmin SQL, rows generated by program

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have a table in PHP MyAdmin and I wanted to insert a sample data into the table. So, I made a program in C++ that returned me a file consisting of 1000 insert queries.
However, when I tried to run it on PHP MyAdmin, it gives error. It does insert 20-30 rows and sometimes even close to 50, but it never inserts all of them and gives this same error every time,

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Chaman', 'Balochistan', 'death');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_ge' at line 1
```

I don't understand and want to know what might be the problem? and how can I resolve this issue? I am able to rewrite my program as per the solution. Thank you...

Just to clarify, this is how few of the insert queries from the text file looks like,

```
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('1', 'Javed Ahsan', 'Male', 'House #59B, Ayub colony', 402669132, 94, 3000000007581, NULL, ' NULL, 'Chaman', 'Balochistan', 'death');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('2', 'Fareed Karim', 'Male', 'House #96B, Namamabad', 402662372, 41, 3000000022870, NULL, ' NULL, 'Muzafarabad', 'AJK', 'death');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('3', 'Kashif Hussein', 'Male', 'House #80B, Unasi', 402672716, 72, 3000000018409, NULL, ' NULL, 'Muzafarabad', 'AJK', 'discharged');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('4', 'Nadia Ayesha', 'Female', 'House #39B, Siddiqua Colony', 402685210, 17, 3000000015425, '3', NULL, 'Rahim yar khan', 'Punjab', 'ACTIVE');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('5', 'Ayesha Humaira', 'Female', 'House #20B, People colony', 402663040, 77, 3000000025766, '2', NULL, 'Mirpur', 'AJK', 'ACTIVE');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('6', 'Zara Lubna', 'Female', 'House #84B, Goli Mar', 402678875, 70, 3000000004732, NULL, ' NULL, 'Sahiwal', 'Punjab', 'discharged');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('7', 'Abeeha Musarrat', 'Female', 'House #79B, Ayub colony', 402684161, 57, 3000000003105, NULL, ' NULL, 'Sibi', 'Balochistan', 'discharged');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('8', 'Khalid Farhan', 'Male', 'House #76B, Bahria Town', 402678130, 63, 3000000000115, NULL, ' NULL, 'Bannu', 'KPK', 'discharged');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('9', 'Ayesha Bushra', 'Female', 'House #76B, Baldia Colony', 402673684, 59, 3000000006222, NULL, ' NULL, 'Jalabad', 'GB', 'discharged');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('10', 'Yasmin Seher', 'Female', 'House #87B, Careem Town', 402663547, 42, 3000000022760, NULL, ' NULL, 'Danyor', 'GB', 'discharged');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('11', 'Sadia Maria', 'Female', 'House #22B, Unasi', 402656552, 88, 3000000010410, NULL, ' NULL, 'Jehlum', 'Punjab', 'discharged');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('12', 'Hafsa Sidra', 'Female', 'House #84B, Gulberg', 402664013, 20, 3000000003814, NULL, '3', 'Peshawar', 'KPK', 'ACTIVE');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('13', 'Bano Faiza', 'Female', 'House #12B, Jhaal Kahanewaal', 402677345, 82, 3000000031644, NULL, '3', 'Sahiwal', 'Punjab', 'ACTIVE');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('14', 'Faraz Mahmoud', 'Male', 'House #27B, Gulshan Town', 402672852, 76, 3000000028060, NULL, ' NULL, 'Nowshera', 'KPK', 'discharged');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('15', 'Akmal Dalir', 'Male', 'House #7B, Goli Mar', 402681204, 87, 3000000008232, '1', NULL, 'Kotli', 'AJK', 'ACTIVE');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('16', 'Fahad Fahad', 'Male', 'House #42B, Mujeeb Town', 402680420, 61, 3000000028178, NULL, ' NULL, 'Mansehra', 'KPK', 'discharged');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('17', 'Milad Haris', 'Male', 'House #89B, Mujeeb Town', 402679110, 26, 3000000008477, NULL, ' NULL, 'Sahiwal', 'Punjab', 'discharged');
insert into patient (patient_id, p_name, p_gender, p_address, p_phone_no, p_age, p_CNIC, p_isolation_id, p_quarantine_id, p_city, p_province, p_status) VALUES('18', 'Irfan Farhan', 'Male', 'House #104B, Siddar', 402662027, 36, 3000000013988, NULL, '1', 'Quetta', 'Balochistan', 'ACTIVE');
```

Comment: Before `Chaman` the `null` value has `'` that causes problem.

Comment: What does the CREATE patient SQL code look like?

Comment: @Ersoy God! Dang it, thank you so much for pointing out the error. Worked perfectly now after resolving this issue. 

Gilber, thanks for the reply too... Create patient though is absolutely fine, issue is resolved now